# Elastic Load Balancing in EC2

Tags: load, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, haproxy

It's been on the cards for a while, but now that Amazon have released [Elastic Load balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) (ELB), what are your thoughts on deploying this solution for a high-traffic web application?

Should we replace [HAProxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAProxy) or consider ELB as a complimentary service in front of HAProxy?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've been running an ELB instead of HAProxy for about a month now on a site that gets about 100,000 visits per day, and I've been pretty pleased with the results.

A gotcha though (UPDATE, this issue has been fixed by [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services), see comments below):

1. You can't load balance the root of a domain as you have to create a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) alias to your load balancer. Once solution is to redirect all traffic from `http://mysite.com` to `http://www.mysite.com`.

Apart from that I really can't speak highly enough of the AWS ELB offerings. I'm also using the Cloudwatch monitoring and autoscaling. Oh and don't forget it's cheaper than running a small [EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance ($0.025 per hour instead of $0.10).

Comment: ELB now has SSL termination capability: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/10/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination.html

Comment: How did you redirect your traffice from http://mysite.com to http://www.mysite.com

Comment: Using a HTTP redirection at the DNS level.

Comment: AWS has just announced that you can map root domains to a load balancer - http://aws.amazon.com/route53/?ref_=pe_2170_19975170#highlights

Comment: You can now get around the root domain issue by using ALIAS records provided by DNSimple.com

Comment: You can get around the root domain apex record by using Route53 A Alias record.

Answer (score 18):

ELB's dependence on DNS CNAME record indirection is pretty crippling for web services that need to be very fast. In our case we need to have very good response time. In a quick performance test, the use of an ELB increased the average latency for HTTP requests by a factor of almost 2. This is mainly because the TTL on the CNAME lookup is zero. Thus, all lookups involve hitting name servers for two different domains, so the name resolution is way slower. (I worry that defeating caching in DNS is simply an abuse of the system.) The only hope for ELB in our case would be to get away from CNAME records by having Amazon support an Elastic IP as the address of a load balancer instance.

Answer (score 10):

Another issue is getting the client IP address.  For regular HTTP this works fine, as ELB sets the X-FORWARDED-FOR header.  But for HTTPS this isn't possible because it is forwarding at the TCP layer.  Hopefully some day ELB will have SSL termination.

Comment: And now it does!

Answer (score 6):

There are complaints in the Amazon forum about ELB's reliability.  I suggest you head over there and search on ELB to form your own opinion on that front.

We wanted to use ELB to load balance web service requests, but we have many external callers, some of which send a 100-Continue HTTP message.  Unfortunately ELB does not understand that part of the HTTP protocol, so we're unable to go beyond proof-of-concept until that's addressed.

**2013 Update**

According to an AWS forum post, HTTP 100-Continue is now supported.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=144022

Comment: sorry to comment on this very old post. But, do you have any idea if the 100-Continue is supported today in ELB ? (I didn't find any recent information about this missing feature)

Comment: @ben75: Apparently it is now supported.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One main problem for many users with ELB is that it does not support stickyness, which is a killer for many web application.

According to [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) developers it should however come in the next release.

Comment: Hi Jeff

What do you mean by stickyness. ?

Comment: Sticky sessions (so that a request from a client always routes to the same server, most commonly implemented with cookies)

Comment: if you are not able to store your session data in a common storage, you should probably should be using an LB. you won't really be balancing any loads :-P 

how about instead, doing the old www1,www2,www3,etc subdomain game if you need that functionality.

Comment: Sticky sessions are a terrible idea and should never be used

Comment: Sticky sessions are supported in ELB as of today! http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/04/08/support-for-session-stickiness-in-elastic-load-balancing/

Comment: I hate to downvote but I agree -- sticky sessions is horrible advice and this defeats 90% of the reason for having a load balancer in the first place

Comment: @Peter - I disagree, they have their place...hint: you used a sticky session to post that comment.  Sticky sessions that automatically recalculate where to "stick" when a backend to the LB goes down are perfectly fine, and have many caching advantages.