# multiple AWS ELBs for a high traffice site ever recomended?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I've seen some blogs online that 1 ELB can [handle 100k or so requests per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877468/elastic-load-balancing-in-ec2). Can it handle more?

Is there ever a scenario where multiple ELBs should be used for 1 website? Is there a best practice for when to add multiple ELBs OR should 1 ELB scale really large (concurrency and total requests per day)?

Note: I use SSL termination at the ELB for my webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out 1 elb is enough for scaling purposes. Multiple ssl certs or availability across regions require more than one however.  ELB slow-scales based on your load, so if you launch something, then slam it with load (lets say you were stress testing something, for example...) ELB can be overwhelmed initially.  The ELB should scale itself up over time to handle the load.